# I want to process 20 TB of pdf files in hadoop in such a way that there is one output per input for each pdf files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, text-processing, apache-tika

I want to process 20 TB of pdf files in spark using tika in such a way that there is one output per input for each pdf files.

I am able to do it in a sequential manner but it is taking a lot of time. When doing it in parallel manner (by giving the input as the whole directory containing pdf files) it is taking very less time but the output is part files containing overlapping values. Is there any way in which I can do it in a parallel manner and get one output per input.

Below is my code :-

```
val binRDD = sc.binaryFiles("/data")

val textRDD = binRDD.map(file => {new org.apache.tika.Tika().parseToString(file._2.open( ))}) textRDD.saveAsTextFile("/output/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of file names in an RDD and then parallelize over it, something like below. I haven't run the code but should probably work or you can tweak it accordingly

EDIT: I have run the below code and it's working for me

```
  val files = new 
  File("C:/Users/mavais/Desktop/test").listFiles().filter(_.isFile()).toList

  val filesRDD = sc.parallelize(files, 10)

 filesRDD.map(r => {
  sc.textFile(r.getPath)
    .map(x=> x.toInt *x.toInt)
    .coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/mavais/Desktop/test/"+r.getAbsolutePath.split("\\\\").last.split("\\.")(0)))
 }).collect()
```

Comment: the output is not unique for each input file, it is overlapping because the partitions in spark is managed by the total file size to block size of hdfs. So which part goes to which data cant be controlled, The input files are of varying sizes ranging from 20 KB to 1 MB

Comment: Here, in the above code, we are processing 10 files in parallel but each of them is read separately in the map because thatfileRDD contains data of 1 particular file so i'm pretty sure the O/P is unique. Can you post your code here please?

Comment: val file= sc.textFile(args(0))

val input1 = file.flatMap(line => line.split("\\s+"))

val input2 = input1.collect()

for (x <- input2){

      val binRDD = sc.binaryFiles(x)

      val textRDD = binRDD.map(file => {new 
org.apache.tika.Tika().parseToString(file._2.open( ))})

      val temp = x.split('/')(3)

      textRDD.saveAsTextFile(s"/$temp/")

      }